# How to delete a specific Hash key and value that is nested with the same key with a button link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

The goal is to remove a specific url from the files.

The Hash -

```
[{"id":2,"job_id":1358,"files":[{"url":"/uploads/job_photo/files/2/signature.png"},{"url":"/uploads/job_photo/files/2/zombie.jpg"}],"url":"https://www.americanpatiodriveandwalk.com/job_photos/2.json"},{"photos":["signature.png","zombie.jpg"]}]
```

I separated each url in files so they each have a button.

The View -

```
<tbody>
      <% @job_photos.each do |job_photo| %>
        <% job_photo.files.each_with_index do |file, index| %>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <%= file %>
            </td>
            <td>
              <%= link_to file.to_s, title: 'View', class: 'btn btn-xs btn-info', role: 'button' do %>
                <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                <% end %>
                  <%= link_to remove_photo_path(job_photo.id, index), title: 'Delete', class: 'btn btn-xs btn-danger', role: 'button', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do %>
                    <i class="material-icons">clear</i>
                    <% end %>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <% end %>
            <% end %>
    </tbody>
```

That is the first link results from the code with 0 for the index -

```
<a title="Delete" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" role="button" data-confirm="Are you sure?" href="/job_photos/2/photo/0/remove_photo">
```

I added the index for the route because I figured I would need it eventually.

The Route -

```
put '/job_photos/:id/photo/:index/remove_photo', to: 'job_photos#remove', as: :remove_photo
```

If I didn't fail miserably yet...this is where I fall to pieces I think in the controller -

```
    def remove
      job_photo = JobPhoto.find(params[:id])
      photo_index = JobPhoto.find(params[:index])
      job_photo[:files][photo_index].delete(:url)
      job_photo.update!(:files)

      flash[:success] = "Photo removed!"
      redirect_to request.referer || root_path
    end
```

The part where I try to delete the url from the hash doesn't even make sense...but I put it there so show my struggle.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out -

```
    def remove
      @job_photo = JobPhoto.find(params[:id])
      total_photos = params[:index].to_i
      if total_photos > 0
        photo_index = params[:index].to_i
        photos = @job_photo.files
        delete_image = photos.delete_at(photo_index)
        delete_image.try(:remove!)
        @job_photo.files = photos
        @job_photo.save
      else
        @job_photo.destroy
      end

      flash[:success] = "Photo removed!"
      redirect_to request.referer || root_path
    end
```

I am sure it can be cleaned up, but works perfectly.